# Spring @Async annotation causes java.io.NotSerializableException?

Tags: spring, serialization, asynchronous

I need to create an asynchronized process with Spring, but when I put `@Async` on my method I get this error

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
```

I have this example, but it does not work:

```
@Autowired
private IServicioClienteAsync servicioClienteAsync;

public void prueba() {
    //testAsync();
    servicioClienteAsync.crearCliente();
}
```

and

```
@Service(value = "servicioClienteAsync")
public class ServicioClienteAsync implements Serializable, IServicioClienteAsync {

  @Autowired
  private WServiceCliente wServiceCliente;

  @Override
  public void crearCliente() {        
      wServiceCliente.test("wiiii");        
  }
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class WServiceCliente{

  @Async
  public void test(String name) {
      System.out.println("init ");
      try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println("finish");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to support the semantics of the `@Async` annotation, Spring needs to attach an [`AsyncExecutionInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/AsyncExecutionInterceptor.html) to intercept calls to the method and specify an [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) on which to execute its code.  I'm guessing that `AsyncExecutionInterceptor` itself is not serializable simply because it holds a reference to an `Executor` which is not very likely to be serializable, or else the developers simply didn't plan on it being serialized.

A typical `Executor` implementation will reference one or more [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) instances to execute on — and `Thread` (like anything else that wraps an OS-level handle or similar construct) is not serializable for good reason; in such a case, even if the `AsyncExecutionInterceptor` were serializable, serialization would fail anyway further along the reference graph.

Comment: ok, but i need this @Async can you tell me any solution, my controller viewscope need serialized and service spring, do you know other way?

Comment: You will not be able to use the `@Async` annotation in a view-scoped bean.  Can you move the `@Async` methods to a session- or application-scoped bean?  If not, an alternative might be to drop the `@Async` and just start a new thread containing the asynchronous code; this is simplified by the method returning `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because your `WServiceCliente` is not `Serializable` while being used by your `Serializable` Service `ServicioClienteAsync` bean?

Comment: not, i test with and without serializable in my class but the error is for org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor

Answer (score 0):

With default configuration I use @EnableAsync(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ) in the configuration of the executor bean and solved the problem.